# How do I retrieve the selected rows of a woodstock table

Tags: jsf, woodstock

I have a JSF woodstock table with checkboxes. When a row is selected I want to do some processing with those items. I managed to get a selection of RowKey objects but can't find out how to get the original objects I put in back. The table is populated by an ObjectListDataProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Always nice to be able to answer you own questions. 
I managed to solve it by casting the table's data provider to ObjectListDataProvider and use the method 'getObject' to get my original object back.

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled across this and was hoping to find how to actually do the selecting and get the row information. I eventually figured it out and I thought others might benefit from how I did it.

I added a RadioButton to a table column in the JSP and added a valueChangeListener

```
<ui:radioButton id="radioButton1" name="radioButton-group1" valueChangeListener="#{MyBeanPage.radioButton1_processValueChange}" />
```

In my Java code I created the valueChangeListener function and stored the current row information.

```
public void radioButton1_processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
  TableRowDataProvider trdp = (TableRowDataProvider)getValue("#{currentRow}");
  setCurrentRowKey(trdp.getTableRow());  //Sets an instance variable for the RowKey
}
```

Now if you have any buttons that want to manipulate the data in the selected row you can do this to get the object data. Jasper mentioned this above.

```
/*getObjectListDataProviderImpl() returns the implementation of 
 *ObjectListDataProvider for your dynamic data.
 */
getObjectListDataProviderImpl().getObject(getCurrentRowKey());
```

You might be able to use something like selectedValue attribute for radio button in conjunction with something else instead of doing valueChangeListener and avoid having to do a valueChange function but this worked so I didn't care to figure out another way.